# Using sudo atom no longer opens Atom at all, let alone as root

Tags: linux, sudo, atom-editor

I'm using the Atom editor. Yesterday, if I typed:

- `sudo atom .`  it opened the current directory as root
- `sudo atom` it opened Atom with whatever I last had open as root

Today if I run either of those commands nothing happens. The editor doesn't open and there are no error messages.

These terminal commands worked yesterday on these exact same files, today they do not.

How can I fix this?
Why is this happening?

If I have not provided enough information it's because I don't know what info one would need to have a fuller explanation of my circumstance. Let me know what I should add I'll happily edit this question to provide it.

```
Atom    : 1.13.0
Electron: 1.3.13
Chrome  : 52.0.2743.82
Node    : 6.5.0

Ubuntu 14.04 LTS
Elementary OS Freya (64-bit)
```

Comment: Version of atom? Operating system? These seem like a minimum.

Answer (score 3):

After updating Atom text editor it seems I require to run --no-sandbox flag but after a while it becomes boring so I wrote a simple BASH script to be doing this for me:

eval "atom --no-sandbox flag"

just save this in a common directory that you frequently use and type ./atom_text_editor.sh in the terminal to deploy(Depending on the name you choose for your script)

Answer (score 0):

A recommendation, when working on linux avoid using sudo or su instrucctions, they are intended to execute privileged instructions like system configurations. It might be related to permissions, execute ls -al and verify that the owner/group of yor files is root, if not, then check if "others" have read permission, if not, then thats is the problem.

Comment: I'm trying PHP/WordPress for the first time and followed a setup tutorial. That tutorial had me put my `wp-config.php` file with root access, so I did. What I'm reading online, for the most part, backs that idea up. It seems like a different question than the one I asked, but I'm open to suggestions to set this up securely and in a manner that will allow me to open my editor of choice to make updates when needed.

Answer (score 0):

Be aware running atom with sudo is **not** recommended.

I've had this problem for a few days, I installed atom using snap (on ubuntu 18.04) a few weeks ago, back then it worked perfectly, but the last few days if i ran 'sudo atom' nothing would happen at all, reinstalled it using snap, still didn't work, removed settings, still didn't work.

I ended up installing atom using the apt packagage manager and now it works. I used this guide: https://codeforgeek.com/install-atom-editor-ubuntu-14-04/

Furthermore when running atom with sudo it should be ran with the --no-sandbox flag.

Conclusion: seems to be a problem with atom when installed using snap.